# Railsで動画のインライン再生を実装したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ruby on Railsで動画のインライン再生を実装したいと考えています。
以下のように記述したところ怒られてしまいました。
どのように実装するのが良いのでしょうか？

```
<%= video_tag @item.content.to_s, loop: true, controls: true, playsinline, class: "content embed-responsive-item" %>
```

Comment: 「怒られてしまいました」とありますが、具体的にどのようなエラーがでたのでしょうか。みた感じ単に`playsinline`が値をもっていなくて構文エラーになっているようですが……

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。

`<%= video_tag @item.content.to_s, loop: true, controls: true, :playsinline => 'true', class: "content embed-responsive-item" %> `

とすることで解決しました。